# Android Vector Asset Studio: Import SVG and use ID as Name

Tags: android, android-studio, android-vectordrawable

I am importing an SVG file as Vector Drawable using Vector Asset Studio. Everytime I do so, it removes the "id" attribute of my SVG in the generated XML file. I thought they would be converted to "name" attribute in the xml file since they are both identifiers.

I created my svg using Inkscape so I could just draw it. Here is a snippet from my svg file:

```
<rect
         inkscape:label="#rect1067"
         y="50.32835"
         x="154.16335"
         height="25.92329"
         width="23.673288"
         id="lobby-link"
         style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;
         stroke-width:0.32671064;stroke-miterlimit:4;
         stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" />
```

Here is a snippet from the generated xml file:

```
<path
        android:fillAlpha="1"
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M154.163,50.328h23.673v25.923h-23.673z"
        android:strokeWidth="0.32671064"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#000000" />
```

Is there a way for me to achieve that the snippet generated will include something like: android:name="lobby-link"?

Answer (score 0):

There is an external Tool called [svg2android](https://inloop.github.io/svg2android/). Although I wouldn`t recommend using it because it is deprecated, it supports converting your IDs to the android name attribute. Simply drag the SVG file you want to convert an click the "*Import IDs from SVG as name*" checkbox.